# What does it mean by Mahout is built on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I have read that Mahout is developed on Hadoop, and that we can use Mahout with or without Hadoop. What does it mean by saying that Mahout algorithms can be run on Hadoop? Mahout algorithms are not written in Map-Reduce form right?Could you please explain to me with an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at the source code? The algorithms are implemented as Map/Reduce jobs (not all, but much of it), which is exactly why this statement is made.

Comment: I have gone through the code of GenericUserBasedRecommender and got to see that it is not in Map-Reduce form, does that mean it is not implemented on Hadoop?

Comment: In that case,I can understand that GenericUserBasedRecommender is a normal Java code which I can convert to Map-Reduce code and run on Hadoop. Please let me know if my understanding is right.

Comment: There are also Hadoop-based versions of this. You can write whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

Mahout has two version non distributed and distributed. There are some basic distributed (Hadoop) implmentations available like ItemBased Collaborative Filtering. The limitation with default distributed are that if your rating data is having userid and item id as alphanumeric then you will need to customise it.

If you want to implement some custom algorithm then you will have to write Mapper and Reducers and even the code for calling them.

I have overriden org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob for using my custom Map and Reduce tasks.

Kindly guys correct me if i am wrong.